# How to create one shapefile between 2000-2010

Tags: qgis, merge

I have different deforestation shapefiles for Amazon region for each year 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003 etc. until 2010. I want to create a new shapefile that will show the data just between 2000-2010 in QGIS. Should I just use merge for this to get correct information?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the tool you might be interested in is 'Union' - try both merge and union and see which suits your needs

Comment: @bleegp - You should consider posting your comment as an answer =)